# Table tr td with checkboxes, apply parent tr class if no checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a small script to my table on this conditions:
I have a table with a checkbox on each tr td and I want to apply my jQuery script only if selector find a tr where all td checkboxes are not checked but if only one checkbox is checked on tr row then do not add class to parent tr.

Basically I need to add a class to parent tr when on entire tr row none of td checkboxes is selected.

> Here is my script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#callScr').on('click', function (e) {
        $(".table tr input:not(:checked)").each(function (i, obj) {
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("yourClass");
        });
    })
});
```

**[Here is my fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16992/)**

Now is adding that class to all tr parents even if I have one checbox selected ...

Comment: Please, explain in a better way what you want to do. It's impossible to understand it. Besides copy your HTML and paste it in this question, after formatting it in a readable way. I've visited your fiddle, and your HTM isn't formatetd at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you want also remove class if checkbox will get checked:

```
$(function(){
    $('#callScr').on('click', function(e){
        $('.table tbody tr').each(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('yourClass',$(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length == 0);
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16995/

Comment: good point ;) but your condition works in reverse, anyway is better to use "toggleClass" but refactor your condition.

Comment: @burebistaruler true, udpated:)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each `tr` in `tbody` and the length of checked checkbox in it. If length is `0` the add class.

```
$(function () {
    $('#callScr').on('click', function(e) {
        $(".table tbody tr").each(function(i, obj) {
            if ($(this).find(":checkbox:checked").length == 0)
                $(this).addClass("yourClass");
        });
    });
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16993/)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the tr's and do that instead and check the inputs inside

```
$(function(){
    $('#callScr').on('click', function(e){
       $( ".table tr:gt(1)" ).each(function(i, obj) {
          if($(this).find('input:checked').length===0)
             $(this).addClass( "yourClass" );
       });
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1p49hvq6/2/) for reference